# How to insert an integer inside a string?

Tags: c++

How do I insert an integer `i` into a string? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFrameBoss1; i++) {
    boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap("boss1//frame_0" + i + "_delay-0.03s.png");
}
```

Comment: @François When I put it in the beginning of the line it says namespace "std" has no member "string"

Comment: You must have forgotten `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert `i` to a string first. Then concatenate the strings. Finally (apparently) get a pointer to char for your `al_load_bitmap`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFrameBoss1; i++) {
    std::string filename = "boss1//frame_0" + std::to_string(i) + "_delay-0.03s.png";
    boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(filename.c_str());
}
```

Comment: why not leave it implicit ?  `std::string filename = "boss1//frame_0" + i + "_delay-0.03s.png";`

Comment: Ok. So it says: 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP *al_load_bitmap(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *'

Comment: @MohammadKanan: Because it won't work. You *can* add an integer to a pointer, so `"boss1//frame_0 + i` yields a result--but the result is that pointer advanced by `i` positions, so if (for example) i = 10, that much basically yields: "me_0". Trying to add that to another string literal won't work.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I insert an "i" variable into a string.

There is a standard library function to convert an `int` to a `std::string`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string.

Use

```
std::string filename = std::string("boss1//frame_0") + std::to_string(i) + "_delay-0.03s.png";
boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(filename);
```

If `al_load_bitmap` cannot use a `std::string`, use:

```
std::string filename = std::string("boss1//frame_0") + std::to_string(i) + "_delay-0.03s.png";
boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: I'm a little curious; how would you feel about `al_load_bitmap(("boss1//frame_0" + std::to_string(i) + "_delay-0.03s.png").c_str())`?

Comment: @Justin, I prefer to use two lines. It's easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Ok. Now it says: 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP *al_load_bitmap(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *'

Comment: @mmarcin8, looks like you need the second version of my suggested solution.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to construct strings from arbitrary input types is to use [**`std::ostringstream`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFrameBoss1; i++) {
    std::ostringstream bitmap_filename_builder;
    bitmap_filename_builder << "boss1//frame_0" << i << "_delay-0.03s.png";
    boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(bitmap_filename_builder.str().c_str());
}
```

When using this, take care about the lifetime of the temporarily created `std::string` variable returned by the [`std::ostrinsgstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) function. The result of the `c_str()` function may become a dangling pointer after execution of that statement.
Be sure that the function you're calling takes a copy of that c-style string parameter, or just uses it in a strongly sequential manner and doesn't store that pointer as a *state* elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to just use `std::to_string(i)`, but that could potentially lead to extra allocations, as `std::string` cannot know the final size in the intermediate `+` operations.

Instead, you may want to use [`absl::StrCat`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings#abslstrcat) or some other variant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFrameBoss1; i++) {
    std::string filename = absl::StrCat("boss1//frame_0", i, "_delay-0.03s.png");
    boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(filename.c_str());
}
```

This is a relatively small performance point, but the solution is easy enough to be worth mentioning.